# 2 way link between cells of already linked worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a Work In Progress (WIP) workbook where all the projects are in different states of repair and the data linked to other sheets based on the state of repair it's in. (Tear Down, In Quoting, WF Approval, Testing, Shipping, ect)

[WIP (Master Sheet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zYHE.png)

I use this script to link them;
In cell A2...

=IF(ISERR(INDEX(MasterEX!$E$1:$E$9999,SMALL(IF(MasterEX!$E$1:$E$9999="Shipping",ROW(MasterEX!$E$1:$E$9999),10000),ROW()-ROW($E$1)+1)-ROW($E$1)+1)),"",INDEX(MasterEX!A$1:A$9999,SMALL(IF(MasterEX!$E$1:$E$9999="Shipping",ROW(MasterEX!$E$1:$E$9999),10000),ROW()-ROW($E$1)+1)-ROW($E$1)+1))

This establishes a 1-way link.
[Shipping sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gd2x.png)

What I need is for a 2 way link for all cells in column N (Work Order Comments & Notes) so that if that cell is updated from the "Shipping" sheet, it will update on the "MasterEX" sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.